# How to plot distribution of each state for Non homogenous hidden Markov Model (NHMM) in R?

Tags: r, distribution, hidden-markov-models

I am working with DepmixS4 package in R. I was able to fit my NHMM by using below code:

`NHMM <- depmix(list(Clust1.North~1,Clust2.North~1,Clust1.South~1,Clust2.South~1), nstates = 4, family=list(gaussian(),gaussian(),gaussian(),gaussian()), data = NHMM.Data, transition = ~Clust1.temp+Clust2.temp)`

`NHMM.fit<- fit(NHMM)`

I would like to plot the distribution of each state of my model.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: It is also not clear what you mean by plotting the distribution of each state. Do you mean the conditional distribution of the observed variables (the "Clust" variables), or do you want to visualise the frequency of each state over the time points?